# How to fix: Context Provider not passing new context values down to children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

i'm new to using React Hooks and React Context and I was wondering why my Context Provider doesn't seem to pass down the new values to a child component. I have it set up where the initial value "ColorContext" is 'red' but I want the value of "ColorContext" in the button to be 'green'. However, when I try to do so, the "ColorContext" value does not change and stays 'red.'

Here is the link to my code: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8mhqwu

```
import React, { Component, useState, useContext, createContext } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const ColorContext = createContext('red')


const App = (props) => {

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <ColorContext.Provider value= {'green'}>
        <button
        style = {{backgroundColor: useContext(ColorContext)}}
        >
          Click here
        </button>
      </ColorContext.Provider>
    </div>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Hook Rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level):

> **Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**
>
> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions**. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.

Thus, have a new consuming component using `useContext` hook as a good practice.

```
const ColorContext = createContext('red');

const Button = () => {
  const value = useContext(ColorContext);
  return (
    <button style = {{backgroundColor: value}}
    >
      {value}
    </button>
  );
};

const App = (props) => {  
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <ColorContext.Provider value={'blue'}>
        <Button />
      </ColorContext.Provider>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need wrap `App` component with context.

```
const App = (props) => {

  return (
    <div className="app">
        <button
        style = {{backgroundColor: useContext(ColorContext)}}
        >
          Click here
        </button>
    </div>
  )
}

render(<ColorContext.Provider value= {'green'}><App /></ColorContext.Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

From the react useContext [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext):

> When the nearest `<MyContext.Provider>` above the component updates, this Hook will trigger a rerender with the latest context value passed to that MyContext provider.
>   ...
>
> `useContext(MyContext)` only lets you *read* the context and subscribe to its changes. You still need a `<MyContext.Provider>` *above* in the tree to provide the value for this context.

What this is saying is that the context needs to be *above* the component you want to update. I.e. it needs to be a parent of the `<App />` component in your example.

Therefore, Giang is right, you'd need to define `<App />` within your `ColorContext.Provider` component.

Answer (score 1):

Because you `useContext` in `App` component. So it will find the `nearest context` above the calling component (`App`) in the tree. The result is not found. So It take the default value ('red') instead the value ('green') you pass in the context in your `App` component. You need to wrap your button to a new component and `useContext` in that component.

```
const ContextButton = () => (
  <button type="button" style={{ backgroundColor: useContext(ColorContext) }}>
    Click here
  </button>
);
```